# C# - Console Keystrokes

Tags: c#, console-application, keystrokes

I want to compare the key pressed in a console to the left arrow key if they are equal meaning the key pressed was the left arrow key, key change the background color of the console to cyan...

I'm not sure how to set up the If statement though, because I dont know how to compare keys in a console.

```
using System;

namespace ConsolePaint
{
class MainClass
{


    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
        keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystrokes 

        if ( keypress.KeyChar == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow )
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = "Cyan";
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystrokes 

if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `keypress.Key` (instead of `.KeyChar`) - also your `"Cyan"` should be `ConsoleColors.Cyan` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
    keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystrokes 
    if ( (int)keypress.Key == (char)ConsoleKey.LeftArrow )
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }
```