# Using Arrow Keys to navigate in the Console

Tags: c#, arrow-keys

Im making a menu. I want to use arrow keys to select from my list.

```
char move;

do
{
    move = (char)_getch();
    if (move == 38)
    {
         // Move Indicator Up   
    }
    else if (move == 40)
    {
         // Move Indicator Down
    }
}
while (move != 13);
```

Am i using the wrong ascii values for up and down keys?

SOLVED

i replaced (char)_getch() to (int)_getch() and char move to int move
 then 38 and 40 to ?? and 80

Comment: what is _getch() ? I see C# like a tag.

Comment: Are you sure this is C# code? Based on your call to `_getch`, it looks more like C.

Comment: it's c#. I tried replacing 38 with 'w' and it worked.

Comment: Are you P/Invoking `_getch()` from `msvcrt.dll`? And if so, **why**?

Comment: i dont now why. i used it in my previous maze game and it works properly. i;m just having a hard time when it comes to arrow keys.

Comment: Instead of marking the question text as "SOLVED" you should accept an answer.

Comment: accept an answer!? I didn't get the answer I want yet. not now. :))

Comment: both answers underneath seem to work :) Are they not what you're looking for? Unless you have a very good reason to, you shouldn't pinvoke c functions into c# if there is a c# counterpart for it already.

Comment: It's solved now. 80 is for down and 72 is for up. Thanks for the effort guys. I'll choose an answer still.

Comment: Uh, you should be using `Console.Read` or `Console.ReadKey`. P/Invoking `_getch()` is definitely the wrong solution. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms395663) for C# equivalents to CRT functions.

Comment: I would have to agree with Cody there

Comment: @ReinanContawi: If no answer was correct because your question was too trivial or too localized to your particular issue, please try to solve it yourself.  Asking a question for every tiny incremental change you make to your code is considered [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) and will result in your account being blocked from asking questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you're DllImporting msvcrt.dll to use _getch()

Try using Console.ReadKey()

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow) {

} else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow) {

} ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In case we are talking about a WinForms application i would recommend you to use the [Control.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx).
"Console.Read()" doesn't work for WinForms applications.

**Update**
Example for menu navigation with arrow key for console application in C#. >> [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351258/c-arrow-key-input-for-a-console-app) [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169072/c-console-keystrokes)